# List All Tags and groups with OPCDA

Tags: c#, opc

I need to list all the tags on an OPCDA server, I Found DLLS(opcnetapi.dll from opcfoudantion) that he uses and I’ve already been able to do the communication, but I can not list the tags that are on the server.
My code is as follows:

```
OpcCom.ServerEnumerator se = new OpcCom.ServerEnumerator();
Opc.Server[] servers = se.GetAvailableServers(Opc.Specification.COM_DA_20);
Opc.Da.Server daServer = (Opc.Da.Server)servers[1];
daServer.Connect();
```

Comment: what is the error? is this undocumented api? if this is the case you are probbly alone. sorry :(

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25174889/982149 They are using a different lib, but the solution should be quite similar. You would just need to "translate" to your lib's API.